# Picking equipment for learning Country Guitar in an apartment.

Tags: electric-guitar, learning, beginner, country-and-western

I want to learn to play country guitar. Right now, I'm at a point in my life where I can dedicate a few hours a day to practice. (3+ hours) But I'm a total newbie to music period and live in a dreaded apartment. I get that I should get an electric guitar, studio quality headphones and a low-wattage amp with headphone jack and/or a computer interface. In-order to practice without driving my neighbors to an untimely suicide. But I can't find anywhere that talks about selecting that equipment in relation to using it for country music. Probably an affordable acoustic guitar is in my near future.  I have a place to play loudly but it's a 1-2 hour drive back and forth.

So is there anything I should avoid or look for in the above electric equipment given that I'm considering using it for country?? Or does it even matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of technique, it doesn't matter.

In terms of sounding like you want to sound playing country music, I suggest you get a headphone amp that allows you to adjust the effects to the sound you're looking for.  Alternatively you could buy a guitar multi-effects board that has a headphone jack.  If you plan to play country music on an electric guitar you could also buy an inexpensive amp with built-in effects that has a headphone jack.  The Roland Cube comes to mind.

Electric country guitar generally uses the same effects as classic rock or 1950s rock for that twang.  Classic rock effects have a wide variety but a good starter would be low mids, medium overdrive, light chorus and a Fender or Marshall amp simulation.  Twang guitar would have reverb, light slap-back delay and a clean tube amp simulation.

Comment: Add some suggestions for which effects should I look for (looking to play popular country music if that helps)  and my question will be fully answered. Thanks for the advice...

Answer (score 1):

You can go with the decent ASIO soundcard (Focusrite 2i2 is one cheap good choice) + some guitar plugins (I use Overloud TH2, Bias FX. You can go cheaper and simpler with Toontrack EZMix + some country emulation addons pr even with free plugins). Or you can go for something like Line6 Amplifi (http://line6.com/amplifi/amplifi-30/). You'll know when you need to invest more :)
Sure, a Telecaster is kind of mandatory. I use a G&L S-500, a guitar made by Leo Fender which is basically a Strat having a Tele sound as well. They also do a very cheap asian version called Tribute which is a very affordable good guitar.

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for traditional chicken picking country guitar sounds then typical equipment would be:

- Telecaster or Stratocaster
- Compressor pedal
- Tube amp or simulator with tube amp sounds

Standard amps are Fender or Dr. Z amps.  So on an effects unit you may be able to find presets of these types of amps.
Also, guitarists to listen to are Brent Mason, Vince Gill, Johnny Hiland, Brad Paisely
Modern country can be anything from Marshalls and Les Paul guitars these days.

Answer (score 0):

Look on youtube for guitar lessons you need to learn a little theroy most songs are 3 chords maby 4 with a minor examble G C & D or A D &E or E A & b start with gc&d then learn basic rythem recommend banjo ben on youtube but there are many others that teach country and blue grass guitar wise it dosent matter as much other than electric or acoustic most country is clean sounding not distorted like rock or metal good country elect guitar fender telecaster or stratocaster good acoustic martin, gibson or taylor but really any guitar that sounds good to you and will stay in tune .

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a reccomendation get an inexpensive acoustic guitar and forget all the other equiptment you can sing with it as well without a pa you can play it anywhere without taking amps cords pedals. country music is basicaly acoustic guitar  or thats how the greats did it and still do hank williams willie nelson george straight george jones garth brooks well you get it I have had many of both electic and acoustic guitars but if I had to pick one it would be an acoustc